# In Angular, how to find the route that "called" the controller from inside the controller?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, angularjs-routing

I know that it's possible for two or more routes to share the same controller. However, at the controller, I would like to know which route "called" it. Why? Which route would determine whether I would load a list of records, load one record by its id, or not load anything at all.

I have the following route configuration:

```
angular.module("app").config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "home.html"
    }).when("/records", {
        templateUrl: "records.html",
        controller: "RecordsController"
    }).when("/record/create", {
        templateUrl: "editRecord.html",
        controller: "RecordsController"
    }).when("/template/edit/:id", {
        templateUrl: "editRecord.html",
        controller: "RecordsController"        
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });

});
```

I want to use only one controller, so I have one:

```
angular.module("app").controller("RecordsController", function($http, $routeParams){
     /* I know that if $routeParams.id exists, it's probably the
        /record/edit/:id route. But if $routeParams.id is null/undefined,
        I don't know which of /records or /record/create "called"
        this controller. I would like to know which route so I can
        decide to load a list (if /records) or not (for /record/create).
     */
});
```

Unless there are some tricks to pull from the route configuration, like with resolve, somehow?

Comment: I've looked at resolve, and it seems like it would crowd the config section too much. I guess resolve "properties" that are functions do become dependencies in a controller. I guess it's a matter of maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use **[`$location.path()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)**

from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based
>   on window.location) and makes the URL available to your application.
>
> ...
>
> ### Getter and setter methods
>
> ```
> // get the current path
> $location.path();
> ```

#### To use in your controller

```
angular.module("app").controller("RecordsController", function($http, $routeParams, $location){
   var path = $location.path();
   // Do something with `path` ...       

});
```

#### Demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/SoRmRFl7gJMxmJ9bXzgS?p=preview

Comment: The question asking for previous controller. I'm also looking for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

import $locationProvider and do a check in your controller for $location.path()

> if($location.path() == '/record")